# Compact Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, stokes-theorem

I'm watching Professor Shifrin's wonderful lectures on Stokes's Theorem, and he uses the term "compact" to describe a manifold. He defines a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as one that is closed and bounded. Does this definition carry over to manifolds?

Comment: Did you consider at least googling compact+math?

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it works. That is the characterization of compact sets in the Euclidean space. However, if you are looking at the manifold as an independent universe, this may not be used as the definition. For instance, the punctured sphere is closed in itself and bounded (since no two points can be separated by a distance bigger than $\pi$) but it is non-compact since the sequence $(\frac{1}{n}, 0, \cdots, 0, \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n^2}})$ has no convergent subsequence (in the punctured sphere).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I did see that compact manifolds can be defined via open covers, and I am curious about whether the sequential or "closed and bounded" definitions hold on manifolds.

Comment: The missing tidbit here is that I never refer to manifolds with nonempty boundary as manifolds. So a compact manifold is necessarily a compact manifold with no boundary. Yes, closed and bounded subset of Euclidian space.

Comment: @TedShifrin the fact that you answer that yourself makes my belief in online education stronger

Comment: Always. @TedShifrin is awesome!

Comment: If you just were to read the Wikipedia article on compactness, you would see that "closed and bounded" is not only inadequate, but meaningless if one were to define compactness for general topological spaces, even for subspaces of manifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, and I know that "closed and bounded" is equivalent to compactness in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Stokes's Theorem holds for compact, oriented manifolds with boundary. Is a compact manifold with boundary defined analogously, or—as my reading of your comment suggests—is there some other approach?

Comment: That is done in the lectures. I don’t know what analogy you have in mind.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for clarifying. I intended to ask whether compact manifolds with boundary might be defined differently than compact manifolds with nonempty boundary because of your previous comment.